# Paypal PHP SDK: Product Unit

Tags: php, paypal, sdk

Is there a way I can set the unit of measurement per quantity of each order item in Paypal ExpressCheckout PHP SDK? Something like 5 bottles, 3 pieces, 500 mL, 120 cm, etc.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there is variable for it but, if you know the correct unit when (in the code) the request is prepared I guess you could add it to the (front of the) product title.

Comment: That made me sad :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to be sad.

```
$Product; // assume this is your orderitem
$unit     = $Product->unit; // or $Product['unit'] if $Product is an array
$quantity = $Product->quantity;
$name     = $Product->name;

//These are dummy variables for PP so you have to substitute them for the real ones. 
$PP_quantity = $quantity;
$PP_name     = $unit . ' ' . $name;
```

If unit is 'bottles' and name is 'some kind of liquid' and quantity is '4', this will output '4 bottles some kind of liquid'. Just as you wanted.

Comment: Just as I feared. Worked OK but would still prefer if Paypal had the "unit" feature. Thanks, BTW. Accepted and upped (+1)

Comment: Oops, can't upvote right now but will do once I get more reputations. 
Thanks again!